# How to keep tab's activities history while switching tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

In my app I have `TabActivity` , and 3 Tabs in it. Every tab has some buttons, that changes current Tabs view. I mean when I'm clicking on the button, it changes the Activity in the current Tab, but when I'm going to second Tab and returning to first one, Tab is recreating. I need to keep the Tab unchanged. How to do this?

Also I didn't  use `fragments` because it needs min API level 11

Thanks in advance